# call on function returns undefined on first call

Tags: angularjs

In my controller i am calling this function in my service. `idservice.getid()`
I am testing it by printing it to console using `console.log(idservice.getid())`

and it returns undefined the first time, but after that if i call it again it returns the value.

I understand this is a async issue but im not sure how to make this work.

my service is below:

```
function idservice (userauth) {

 var id;

  this.getid = function() {
    userauth.currentUser().then(function(user) {
      id = user.id;
    });

    return id
  }
}
```

How can i make it so that on the first call it doesnt return undefined? Is this a async issue?

Comment: this is not an issue, this is how you programmed it: it returns undefined because the id is not yet known and you cannot fix that but you can react on that instead

Comment: What do you mean react on it instead? @smnbbrv Thanks!

Comment: return id from inside of then and also 'catch' it or failed response & return appropriate response

Comment: @Shantanu If i try returning in then, its always undefined, its weird.

Answer (score 0):

This's happening because inside userauth currentUser() method you're making http call and response ('user.id') is yet not available. You can return the userauth.currentUser() call inside getid() method & also return id inside its success callback then. So your service method should look like

```
function idservice (userauth) {

 var id;

  this.getid = function() {
    return userauth.currentUser().then(function(user) {
              id = user.id;
              return id;
            });

  }
}
```

And inside controller you should handle it like

```
idservice.getid().then(function(response){
  $scope.id  = response;
});
```

Here's small example of your requirement: https://plnkr.co/edit/bEjR9e179aRPfJiaQpei?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem today, seems like if you request some data from the server and you assign it to a variable THEN you try to print it, it will show undefined on the first call, I think this is not something it should happen since you are trying to print it AFTER you got the information, but whatever.

I fixed it by removing that variable, just got the data then printed it.

I think this will solve your problem (the OP's last login is 2 years ago, but maybe it will help somebody else that encountered this and didn't found a useful answer?)

```
function idservice (userauth) {

  this.getid = function() {
    return userauth.currentUser().then(function(user) {
              return user.id;
            });

  }
}
```

This will return the user.id as it is, it will not store it in a variable, you want it to be stored in a variable ? Store it, but don't print that variable, something like this :

```
function idservice (userauth) {

 var id;

  this.getid = function() {
    return userauth.currentUser().then(function(user) {
              id = user.id;
              return user.id;
            });

  }
}
```

This worked for me (or at least the logic behind it worked).